# loop through multiple slices of an array in R

Tags: r, arrays, loops, slice

I am trying to loop through an array that has multiple slices, and would like my result to each time show up in the corresponding slice (e.g., I multiply my vector by "m", and I would like the vector to show up in a specific column in the slice "m" of the array).
However, when I do it, the loop overwrites each time the preceding loop, meaning I only get results in the last slice and for the biggest m.

I created a dummy data with code so you can see where I am trying to go. Can somebody help me?

First try, easier code:

```
for(m in 1:3){
array.try <- array(NA,
                     dim=c(8,
                           3,
                           3),
                     dimnames= list(c(1:8),
                                    c("hello", "hi", "man"),
                                    c("sheet", "damn", "hard"))) 


vector.try <- c(1:4)
array.try[,"hello",] <- rep(vector.try, 
                             each = 2) 

vector.try.2 <- c(5:8)
array.try[,"hi",] <- rep(vector.try.2, 
                            each = 2) 
vector.base <- rep(1,8)

array.try[,"man",m] <- vector.base*m
 
}#m
array.try
```

As you can see, the results are all in the last slice of the array, and for the biggest "m".
On top of that, what I actually want is closer to this:

```
for(m in 1:3){
  for(n in 5:7){
array.try <- array(NA,
                     dim=c(8,
                           3,
                           3),
                     dimnames= list(c(1:8),
                                    c("hello", "hi", "man"),
                                    c("sheet", "damn", "hard"))) 


vector.try <- c(1:4)
array.try[,"hello",] <- rep(vector.try, 
                             each = 2) 

vector.try.2 <- c(5:8)
array.try[,"hi",] <- rep(vector.try.2, 
                            each = 2) 
vector.base[[n]] <- rep(1*n,8) 
#this does not work. my goal is to get something similar as 
#assign(paste("vector.base",n, sep =""), rep(1*n,8))
#because this formulations is annoying and brings all kinds of bugs I read online

end.vector <- c(vector.base[[n]])
#my goal here woulb be to have on vector with all the values 
#of the various vector.base1, vector.base2,....
#so basically c(vector.base1, vector.base2,...)

array.try[,"man",m] <- end.vector*m
  }
}#m
array.try
```

But what I really need is mostly to resolve my first issue, aka filling each slice of the array.

Thanks a lot!

Maude

Comment: In your first chunk, move the definition of the `array.try` outside the loop.  As you've got it right now, each time through the loop it re-defines `array.try` to its initial state.

Comment: Thank you so much ! My problem is that in my real code, I define the parameters to create the array (e.g the number of columns and of rows) in the loop itself. How can I deal with that ?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly without seeing the real code, but you can't both overwrite the object (by defining it anew inside the loop) and have it persist under the same name.  If the array changes dimensions for each iteration of the loop, how do you want the results from one iteration to propagate to the next iteration?

Comment: I understand the issue. Thanks a lot for your help. I guess I will have to find a way to rename the matrix each time in the loop so that it doesn't overwrite itself.